# Simple language news site possibly with media

Tags: linguagem

I am looking for some website where I can obtain Portuguese news - preferably in Portuguese of Portugal - in simple language. It could be just text, but if it had audio or video (podcast or vodcast) even better... Examples in simple German language are [Nachrichten-Leicht](http://www.nachrichtenleicht.de/) and news provided by the northern TV/radio station [NDR](http://www.ndr.de/fernsehen/service/leichte_sprache/).

Comment: I used to read sapo.pt, and the essay-style articles there were particularly non-conversational in tone .. and so were approachable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about "simple", but you can look at the Portuguese mass media. It has few colloquialisms and, in video clips, generally good diction, so in those respects it may easy to understand:

- [*RTP*](http://rtp.pt), website of the public television. Some written news articles, [*huge* amount of program archives](http://www.rtp.pt/play/programas). Also online streaming of their TV and radio channels.
- [TVI/Media Capital](http://www.tvi24.iol.pt/), similar content, from a private media company.
- Newspapers: [Público](http://www.publico.pt/) (old orthography...), [Expresso](http://expresso.sapo.pt/), [Diário de Notícias](http://www.dn.pt/), [Jornal de Notícias](http://www.jn.pt/paginainicial/), [Correio da Manhã](http://www.cmjornal.xl.pt/multimedia.html), [O Observador](http://observador.pt/), [Sábado](http://www.sabado.pt/). They have video clips in some news articles as well.

Comment: I advise against *Correio da Manhã*. I find its quality to be below standard.

Answer (score 1):

> Hold On Angola é um portal informativo angolano

https://holdonangola.com

Comment: Re: Hold On Angola: "Creating the new tags 'angola backlinks autoridade marketing' requires at least 150 reputation. Try something from the existing tags list instead. Não entendo isso." — Aparentemente você tentou, por acidente ou não, criar uma _tag_ (etiqueta, palavra-chave) antes de ter reputação o bastante para tal.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo contributo.